# Using jQuery (ajax) with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, typescript

I have installed the jQuery typings in my TypeScript project. I can type $.ajax(...) without any compile errors in VS Code. However, when I check it in localhost, I get an error saying that "$ is not defined". I tried to fix it by importing jQuery like so:

```
 import * as jQuery from "jquery"
```

I imported express in the same way, and it works.

When I type "jquery." in VS Code, VS Code auto-suggests "ajax" as a method call, so it knows about my import. But when I check it in localhost again, it tells me jquery.ajax is not a function.

My test ajax call:

```
jquery.ajax("test.html", {
            success: function () {
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
```

How can you make an ajax call with jQuery with TypeScript?

Comment: You're probably not including the jQuery script in your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

What typings do is tell your TypeScript what methods are safe to interact with a certain JavaScript (*not* TypeScript) file. They're like header files in C++. You still need to actually have the relevant code imported to your page in some way. A basic way to do so would be to add something like this in your HTML's `<head>`:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
```

If you're not using a module system like CommonJS or AMD (something you would have to set up yourself), you may want to remove the `import` statement as it's liable to confuse you.